# Lift: how to build forms with designer friendly templates?

Tags: scala, lift

As a test, I'm trying to create a form in lift with a designer friendly template.
I'm using Lift 2.5

I already managed to create a working form using toForm, but I'm just exploring all possible ways.

My html file contains the code below:

```
...
<span class="lift:Util.entry?form=post">
  <span id="etitle"></span>
  <span id="ebody"></span>
  <span id="esubmit"></span>
</span>
...
```

And in my Util.scala I defined the entry snippet like below:

```
def entry = {
  "#etitle *" #> SHtml.text(title, title = _)
  "#ebody *" #> SHtml.text(body, body = _)
  "#submit *" #> SHtml.submit("Save", saveEntry)
}
```

All the spans remain empty; what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Didn't you forget to merge the transformations ( `#>` ) with the ampersand ( `&` ) ?

```
def entry = {
  "#etitle *" #> SHtml.text(title, title = _) &
    "#ebody *" #> SHtml.text(body, body = _) &
    "#esubmit *" #> SHtml.submit("Save", saveEntry)
}
```

Comment: Also the last css selector `#submit` should probably be `#esubmit` to match the last span.

Comment: @Vasya Novikov, thank you for your answer but could you possibly edit you post to include an example of the corrected code? It might be very useful to  Lift newbies, Thanks!